# After updating MySQL, getting strange JOIN errors

Tags: mysql

I updated to the latest MySQL, and I'm getting this error:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
> nonaggregated column 'date' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

My table:

```
id    int(255)
date  datetime
```

My query:

```
SELECT DATE(date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, COUNT(DISTINCT  id)
FROM  table
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with this query. I get that there must be new syntax rules in this new version of MySQL, but I'm not sure how to follow them with this query.

Comment: `date` is not a reserved word, stellar idea, [probably not](http://i.imgur.com/oUwa6hG.jpg)

Comment: `DESC` in `group by` clause? Are you sure that you want to use `grup by` and not an `order by`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, the MySQL optimizer isn't smart enough to recognize the the expression  `DATE(date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY`  is functionally dependent on `DATE(date)`. The workaround for that is to include the entire expression in the GROUP BY clause.

In the second example, MySQL is griping about the non-aggregates in the SELECT list which aren't in the GROUP BY clause, again, because they aren't functionally dependent.

Here's some example table data that demonstrates the rationale behind the error:

```
id  user  course 
--  ----  ------
11  fee    win101
12  fi     win101
13  fo     win101
```

When we attempt to run this query:

```
SELECT t.course, t.user
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.course
```

There are three possible values that could be returned for `user`... fee, fi or fo.

MySQL will allow the query to run if we use an aggregate expression in place of the column. In this example, we could use MIN(t.user)  or MAX(t.user), and MySQL would return "fee" or "fo", respectively.

MySQL will run this query:

```
SELECT t.course 
     , MIN(t.user)  AS min_user
     , MAX(t.user)  AS max_user
     , COUNT(1)
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.course
```

Answer (score 0):

The `COUNT(DISTINCT  id)` is an aggregation function so it's allowed to be in select clause with `group by`. But the `DATE(date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY` is not an aggregation function and it's not appear in `group by` cluase so this is a reason of your error.

To solve this problem you should add your not aggregated column into `group by` clause like in this query

```
SELECT DATE(`date`) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, COUNT(DISTINCT  id)
FROM  playtime
GRUP BY DATE(`date`) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

More information about `group by` and aggregation functions you can find [here].[1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: But the explanation is the same - your columns `course_difficulty` and `time_taken` should appear on `grup by` clause or you have to use them with aggregation function like `max`, `sum`, etc.